# Hide or change Android default system Toast

Tags: android, permissions, system, default, toast

I've got a problem with the system default toasts in my application. In the config options I let my users to choose if they want to add shortcuts for every point of entry of my activities, and this create a bunch of shortcuts in the home menu.

Since I am changing these shortcuts constantly via cloud api and some tricks, I've decided to delete and create again the shortcuts in the background every time the user logs in the applications. So here's the point, the user gets spammed by the default system toast "Deleting 'Name' shortcut" and "Creating 'Name' shortcut". Since I'm deleting&creating 3 to 5 shortcuts, this is such a big spam.

I wanted to hide this default toasts or maybe change its colors or whatever in order to don't interfere with my app, because they take a long time to disappear.
I've been trying to find a workaround for this but no way. Any idea/suggestion will be very appreciated.

I've already seen Dianne Hackborn answer about this topic, but I wanted to know if there's any viable option.

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: You can build your own ROM mod, containing a modified firmware, that suppresses these `Toasts`, then deploy that ROM mod to your device.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and your time but I want to solve it for my users, not me. And of course that wouldn't work in a google play-oriented app.